docker desktop not starting on debian
i have a problem with docker desktop (debian): one container produces A LOT of log messages (a postgres server with huge queries). There are so many error messages that docker desktop freezes when i click on the log tab for the container.
Do solve this i read that an option is to change the logging driver for docker desktop.
what i have done is to change .user/.docker/daemon.json to the following:
{
    "log-driver": "local",
    "log-opts": {
    "max-file" : 3,
        "max-size": "10m"
    },

    "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false
}

but now docker desktop does not start anymore :/
is something wrong with the json?
or is there anything else to prevent docker desktop to crash whenever i click the log tab?

the issue seems to be the 3 - "max-file" : needs to be "3" instead of 3.

You don't need Docker Desktop on a native-Linux host.  It may be more efficient to directly run the Docker engine directly than to run it inside a Linux virtual machine.
